# Random correlation matrices

Tags: uniform-distribution, partial-correlation, matrix-inverse, accept-reject, precision-matrix

Suppose that we simulate random $n\times n$ correlation matrices by assigning iid $U(-1,1)$ random variables to all off-diagonal entries and accept matrices $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ that are positive definite.  The marginal distributions of each correlation coefficient are then obviously no longer uniform.

Based on simulations including the one below,
the associated [partial correlations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation#Using_matrix_inversion) on the other hand (defined in the usual way as $-p_{ij}/\sqrt{p_{ii}p_{jj}}$ where $\mathbf{P}=\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}$) appear, surprisingly, to each have uniform marginals.

Why is this?  I suppose this can perhaps be proven via matrix calculus but I suspect that there must be a simple explanation.

It is trivially true for $2\times 2$ matrices.  For a $3\times 3$ correlation matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
u_1 & 1 \\
u_2 & u_3 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
the partial correlation matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
\frac{u_2u_3-u_1}{\sqrt{(1-u_2^2)(1-u_3^2)}} & 1 \\
\frac{u_1u_3-u_2}{\sqrt{(1-u_1^2)(1-u_3^2)}} & \frac{u_1u_2-u_3}{\sqrt{(1-u_1^2)(1-u_2^2)}} & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so one approach would be to derive the joint density of the lower triangular entries from the uniform density of $u_1,u_2,u_3$ using standard methods and then integrate out two of the partial correlations.

```r
set.seed(1)
n <- 5
Sigma <- diag(n)
partialcorr <- replicate(10000,{
  repeat{
    u <- runif(n*(n-1)/2, -1, 1)
    Sigma[lower.tri(Sigma)] <- u
    Sigma[upper.tri(Sigma)] <- t(Sigma)[upper.tri(Sigma)]
    if (sum(eigen(Sigma)$val>0)==n)  
      break()
  }
  P <- solve(Sigma)
  D <- diag(1/sqrt(diag(P)))
  (D %*% P %*% D)[lower.tri(P)]
})
hist(c(partialcorr))
```

[image]